# ElementTree prettyprint blank lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree, pretty-print, minidom

I'm using the lines of code below to prettyprint elementtree object in python 2.7:

```
xml_str = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(tgt_xml.getroot())).toprettyxml(indent="\t", encoding='utf-8')
with open(final_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(xml_str)
```

It does it's job, but adds 2 blank lines after each line of xml ... so in result it looks like

```
<Workflow name="Some_name">


    <taskWorkflow>


        <taskWorkflow retainSysIds="false">


            <variables>


                <variable>


                    <description/>
```

Does anybody know how to prettyprint elementtree without the blank lines?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a Windows CR/LF thing?

Comment: Looks like the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/45525198/407651

Comment: @mzjn yes, it seems like the same problem, but it's not answere though